# How can I get the last added data on a hdfs file?

Tags: hadoop, jdbc, hive, mapreduce

I have data coming at a rate onto a HDFS file. I have an external hive table built on top of it. Data has a timestamp column and an int column. 
Every 5 minutes, a row will be added.

I have a JDBC program which needs to check this lastly added row if the int column value has exceeded a limit or not. I thought I would just write a search query for the new timestamp, fetch the row and check its int column value. But, it goes through the entire table to search for the last appended row.

I can create an index on the timestamp column. Is there any other way I can retrieve the recently added data such that performance doesn't go down?

Answer (score 1):

Partition your table by date (say load_date) which you can derive from your timestamp field using `date()` function.  Of course you will need also to modify the process inserting new data or to put it in proper load_date location + execute `alter table add partition` on your external table or [recover partitions](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-RecoverPartitions(MSCKREPAIRTABLE)) if it loads files directly into table location.
Then filter by load_date + timestamp to get last record. It will query only last day partition data.

Comment: But in my case, it will create a lot of partitions if I partition by date. A row is added every five minutes. I have data of years. So it would create so many partitions.

Also, how about indexing on timestamp column, would it help?

Comment: @DivyaMyntra If you partition by date (not timestamp), the number of partitions will be one per day. Not  many. The number of files will be accordingly one file each 5 minutes =~ 300 files in each partition. And this will give you the best performance because you can filter by date and partition pruning will work. It is much better than index.

Comment: Let's say, I have ten years of data. There will be 365*10 dates approx.
That many partitions isn't good. Is it?

Comment: @DivyaMyntra Why not? Daily partition is quite common. How to partition table should be determined based on how that table will be queried or inserted. And your requirement completely matches.

Comment: I'm a complete newbie. I have read somewhere that too many partitions impose so much load on namenode and that's why it isn't good.

Correct me if I'm wrong. Thanks

Comment: @DivyaMyntra As I already said daily partitioning is quite common and it seems it matches your scenario. Too small partitions is not good. Complex key partitions is not good. But the rule is partitioning=usage scenario. Why don't you check how it works

Comment: I'm using an external table. I'll have to create directories myself, right?

Comment: @DivyaMyntra You can, not necessarily have to. you can create new partitioned table and reload old data using insert overwrite partition select from old table. For new data you can load using LOAD command or insert overwrite partition. External table behaves the same as managed except DROP statement behaviour. DROP partition or table for external table will not drop data. For managed it will drop. No other difference